# How to get text in-between two symbols using Python

Tags: python, string, extract

I need to extract a name and an email address out of a string using Python. How would I be able to do this if the format the string is:

[Link to a picture of it since stackoverflow doesn't allow brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEdJA.png)

The name is between quotation marks and the email is between the angle brackets. How could I extract these?

Comment: Have you tried simply: `re.findall(r'"(.*)".*<(.*)>',  '"John Doe" <johndoe@gmail.com>')`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer, I did:

```
name, email = re.match(r'"(.*)" <(.*)>', '"John Doe" <johndoe@gmail.org>').groups()
```

after doing this name and email will be assigned accordingly

Comment: you can take a look at : regexr.com/5nh2l